# I have to double click on cell to paint it in color - JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html-table, cell

I have a table in my `HTML` with the `onclick` event like this:

```
<table onclick="cellClicked();">
```

The problem is that to start coloring the cells in the table I have to previously click on any place in the table. The function that paints the cells is:

```
function cellClicked() {

  var table = document.getElementsByTagName("table")[0];
  var cells = table.getElementsByTagName("td");

  for (var i = 0; i < cells.length; i++) {
    var cell = cells[i];
    cell.onclick = function() {
      var columnIndex = this.cellIndex;
      var rowIndex = this.parentNode.rowIndex;
      var rowSelected = table.getElementsByTagName('tr')[rowIndex];
      var cellSelected = rowSelected.getElementsByTagName('td')[columnIndex];
      cellSelected.style.backgroundColor = "black";
    }
  }
}
```

Thank you very much for the help. A greeting!

Comment: You could just execute cellClicked in the javascript and have the cells onClick color handler set on initialization.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apply the cell's onClick handlers in the javascript.

You could:

1. call it immediately after defining it,
2. wait for DOM content to load then execute it, or
3. only call the function setting up the cell onClicks when the table is rendered.

```js
function initCellClickers() {
  var table = document.getElementsByTagName("table")[0];
  var cells = table.getElementsByTagName("td");

  for (var i = 0; i < cells.length; i++) {
    var cell = cells[i];
    cell.onclick = function() {
      var columnIndex = this.cellIndex;
      var rowIndex = this.parentNode.rowIndex;
      var rowSelected = table.getElementsByTagName('tr')[rowIndex];
      var cellSelected = rowSelected.getElementsByTagName('td')[columnIndex];
      cellSelected.style.backgroundColor = "black";
    }
  }
}

// 1. just call it immediately, it'll set up the click handler when it initializes.
initCellClickers()

// 2. you might need to wait for content to load
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', e => { 
  initCellClickers() 
})

// 3. or if the table is conditionally rendered: 
if(/*table rendered condition*/) {
  initCellClickers()
}
```

Let me know if this works for you or if you have any questions.

Comment: call it immediately after defining it works !!!  thanks u very much !! :)

Answer (score 0):

What about if we attach a `click` event on each `td` elements. I have changed the code a bit.

Please find an example - just replaced with a random `table` for representation:

```js
const table = document.getElementById('yourTable');
const cells = table.getElementsByTagName('td');

for (let i = 0; i < cells.length; i++) {
  cells[i].addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    cells[i].style.backgroundColor = 'black';
  });
}
```

```html
<table id="yourTable">
  <tr>
    <th>Firstname</th>
    <th>Lastname</th>
    <th>Age</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Jill</td>
    <td>Smith</td>
    <td>50</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Eve</td>
    <td>Jackson</td>
    <td>94</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

I hope this helps!